# Last Position function

Tags: list-manipulation

The `FirstPosition[]` function can be use to locate the first position of an occurrence in a list. For example `FirstPosition[list,_?NumericQ]` will find the position of the first occurrence of a number in a list. Is there a function to find the last position of a occurrence? If not perhaps someone has a clever way to do it.

Comment: `FirstPosition[Reverse@list,_?NumericQ]`?:)

Comment: Don't forget:  one then needs to do the proper counting:  `Length[list]-FirstPostion[Reverse@list,_?NumericQ]`.

Comment: @David,  right... whoops;)

Comment: @DavidG.Stork Actually some testing shows you need `(Length[list]+1)-FirstPosition[list,_?NumericQ]`

Comment: @Wintermute Ah yes.  A matter of simple counting.

Comment: ... it gets more complicated if `list` is not a flat list. For nested lists such as `expr={{a,b,2},{c,3,{x,5}},{u,r}}`, `Position[expr,_?NumericQ,Infinity][[-1]]` is much simpler than anything  using `FirstPosition`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The clean but inefficient way is to simply find all positions and take the last one:

```
x = {16, {10, {78, 1}, 32, 15}, 30, 30}

Position[x, _?OddQ][[-1]]
```

> ```
> {2, 4}
> ```

It proves faster to reverse *everything* and use `FirstPosition`:

```
lastPosition[x_, pat_] :=
  Module[{rev, pos},
    rev = Reverse[HoldComplete[x], 1 + Range @ Depth @ x];
    pos = Rest @ FirstPosition[rev, pat];
    1 - pos + Length /@ Unevaluated @@@ FoldList[Part[#, {1}, #2] &, rev, Most@pos]
  ]

lastPosition[x, _?OddQ]
```

> ```
> {2, 4}
> ```

Timing on a large expression:

```
SeedRandom[4]
x =
 Nest[
   RandomChoice[{
     {#, #2} &,
     {#2, #} &,
     Prepend,
     Append
   }][#, RandomInteger[99]] &,
   {1},
   2000
 ];

Needs["GeneralUtilities`"]

Position[x, _?OddQ][[-1]] // AccurateTiming
lastPosition[x, _?OddQ]   // AccurateTiming
```

> ```
> 0.374521
>
> 0.000297869
> ```

Both output:

> ```
> {2, 1, 1, 1, 3, 2, 2, 2, 4}
> ```