# Find list item before first negative value

Tags: list-manipulation, sorting

If I have a list like this:

```
{{117.638, 0.0295688}, {115.988, -2.20012}, {114.338, -9.85732}, {112.688, -4.56951}, {111.038, -5.66421}, {109.387, -2.1389}, {107.737, -8.00359}, {106.087, -1.45329}, {104.437, 3.27452}, {102.787, -0.322676}, {101.137, -5.95987}, {99.4871, 0.115437}, {97.8371, -6.00676}, {96.187, -4.66645}, {94.537, -0.0761449}, {92.8869, 0.276661}, {91.2369, 4.90947}, {89.5868, 3.37977}, {87.9368, -1.65742}, {86.2867, 0.0303858}, {84.6366, 12.9757}, {82.9866, 6.086}, {81.3365, 1.5363}, {79.6865, 9.41411}, {78.0364, 1.32692}, {76.3864, 4.32472}}
```

And I want to find the list entry, starting from the bottom, just before the first negative value of the last item in each row, what is the easiest way to do this?

For example, in the list above, I would want to pull out `{92.8869, 0.276661}`.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest that: 1) You take the introductory [Tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) now! 2) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)! 3) As you receive help, try to give it too, by answering questions in your area of expertise.

Comment: If I understand the question correctly it is not `{92...,...}` but `{86.2867, 0.0303858}` which is the correct result.

Comment: It is unclear what you are asking.

Comment: Related, possible duplicate: [(77422)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/77422/121)

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that the correct answer  is `{86.2867, 0.0303858}` as noted in @Pickett's comment:

```
ClearAll[f]
f = With[{lst = Reverse@#, pos = LengthWhile[Reverse@#, #[[2]] > 0 &]}, 
    If[pos == 0, {}, lst[[pos]]]] &;
```

Example:

```
lst = {{117.638,  0.0295688}, {115.988, -2.20012}, {114.338, -9.85732},
  {112.688,  -4.56951}, {111.038, -5.66421}, {109.387, -2.1389}, 
  {107.737, -8.00359}, {106.087, -1.45329}, 
  {104.437,  3.27452}, {102.787, -0.322676}, {101.137, -5.95987}, 
  {99.4871,  0.115437}, {97.8371, -6.00676}, {96.187, -4.66645}, 
  {94.537,  -0.0761449}, {92.8869, 0.276661}, {91.2369, 4.90947}, 
  {89.5868,   3.37977}, {87.9368, -1.65742}, {86.2867, 0.0303858}, 
  {84.6366,  12.9757}, {82.9866, 6.086}, {81.3365, 1.5363},
  {79.6865,  9.41411}, {78.0364, 1.32692}, {76.3864, 4.32472}};

f@lst
{86.2867, 0.0303858}
```

Also

```
ClearAll[f2]
f2[{___, {_, _?Negative}, z : {_, _?Positive} ..}] := {z}[[1]]
f2[_] := {}

f2@lst
(* {86.2867, 0.0303858} *)
f2@lst[[;; -8]]
(* {} *)
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to Reverse the list...

```
lst[[Last@Position[lst, {_, x_ /; x < 0}] + 1]]
(* {{86.2867, 0.0303858}} *)
```

Comment: ... but it is better if you do: [(77482)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/77482/121)

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Can't check on my poor man's v9

Comment: @Mr.Wizard.  Here is the timing from version 10.1 and a list of `6815744` pairs. @kguler `0.126`, @bbgodfrey `0.212`, @Nasser (with `First@` inserted before `Position`) `3.371`, @Belisarius 6.110.  My (bbgodfrey) solution with the extra `Reverse` eliminated, `0.132`.  The variation in timing from one run to the next is of order 10%.

Comment: @belisarius: Fear not, by the time 11.0 comes out, at the rate they're going with superfluous functions, it will *have* `FindListItemBeforeFirstNegativeValue[]`...

Answer (score 1):

```
{r, c} = Position[data, FirstCase[Reverse@data, x_ /; x < 0, "", 2]];
data[[r + 1]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

To make this more robust, more error checking is needed of course, as the above assumes there is at least one more row after the one found etc... but I am sure you can add these error checking.

Answer (score 1):

This also works.

```
First@Take[Reverse[lst], First@Position[Reverse[lst], {_, z_} /; z < 0, {1}, 1] - 1]
(* {86.2867, 0.0303858} *)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Flatten@lst[[Last@Position[Partition[Negative@lst[[All, 2]], 2, 1], {True, False}]]]
```

{87.9368, -1.65742}